# Unable to conditionally commit/rollback transaction

Tags: mariadb, aws

I am trying to create a reuable SQL script that I can run that will guard against unintentional db changes based on the expected number of affected rows (not looking to create a sproc/func at this time.)

Using the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40691421/3246805), I tried implementing the same but am not having much luck.

I have...

```sql
/*create table test (
    val int
);
insert into test (val) values (1);
insert into test (val) values (2);
insert into test (val) values (3);
insert into test (val) values (4); */


SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
set @@autocommit = 0; /* troubleshooting, doesnt seem to affect outcome */
start transaction;

set @expected = 2;  /* should cause rollback */

delete from test where val > 3;

set @rc = Found_rows();
select @rc as row_count;

set @tran = (select if(@rc = @expected,'ROLLBACK','COMMIT'));
prepare stmt from @tran;
execute stmt;

select * from test;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

But it appears to be committing the transaction no matter what.

I don't imagine it matters, but this is on an AWS RDS (10.0.24-MariaDB) via MySQL Workbench 6.3

I'm more familiar with MSSQL (if that helps any.)

**PS:** Also found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47175417) (which I am less certain about.)

Comment: What happens if you "delete from test where val > 2" ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - leaving all the rest the same, it deletes vals 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in your script.

First, delete does not affect "Found_rows()" if you don't have a "returning".  You should use

```
set @rc = row_count();
```

Second, your logic in the if(cond,trueval,falseval) is inversed, you should use

```
set @tran = (select if(@rc = @expected,'COMMIT','ROLLBACK'));
```

You want to commit when the result equals what you expected, don't you?